# Update NGXS state for an object inside array

Tags: ngxs

I have NGXS state defined as array.

```js
interface Sample {
 name: string;
 age: number;
}

@State<Sample[]>({
  name: 'samples',
  defaults: [] as Sample[]
})
@Injectable()
export class SampleState {
}
```

Now let us say I have an existing state of `[{name:'abc', age: 1}, {name: 'def', age:2}]`

How can I add an action that modifies the age for an Sample based on name and updates the state.
If it is an object I could use simple patchState, but here state is an array so I am not sure.

```js
  @Action(SampleActions.UpdateAge)
  updateAge(context: StateContext<Sample[]>, action: SampleActions.UpdateAge): void {    
  }
```

This is my defined action in SampleActions

```js
  export class UpdateAge{
    static readonly type = '[Sample] Update Age';
    constructor(public name: string, public age: number) {}
  }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way in NGXS is to use [State Operators](https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/operators#supplied-state-operators) - in this case, the provided  `updateItem` operator.

E.g. refactoring your state model a little

```js
interface SamplesStateModel { 
  samples: Sample[];
}

@State<SamplesStateModel>({
   name: 'samples' 
  }
)
export class SamplesState {
 
   @Action(SampleActions.UpdateAge)
   updateAge(context: StateContext<Sample[]>, action: SampleActions.UpdateAge): void { 
     const updatedSample: Sample = { name: action.name, age: action.age };
     context.setState(
        patch({
          samples: updateItem<Sample>(sample => sample.name === action.name, updateSample)
        })
     );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Garth Mason's answer it's also possible without an array-wrapper interface by using [updateItem](https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/operators#supplied-state-operators) directly.

```js
@State<Sample[]>({
  name: 'samples',
  defaults: [] as Sample[],
})
@Injectable()
export class SamplesState {

  @Action(SampleActions.UpdateAge)
  updateAge(
    context: StateContext<Sample[]>,
    action: SampleActions.UpdateAge
  ): void {
    const updatedSample: Sample = { name: action.name, age: action.age };
    context.setState(
      updateItem((sample) => sample?.name === action.name, updatedSample)
    );
  }
}
```