# NGXS : cannot pass objects to "setState" when one of the patched inner fields is nullable or undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

I have this class meant for storing a state in my angular components:

```
export class MyStateModel {
  subState1: SubStateModel1;
  substate2: SubStateModel2;
}
```

It contains simple subclasses :

```
export class SubStateModel1 {
  someField1: string;
}

export class SubStateModel2 {
  someField2: string;
}
```

Somewhere is my Angular code, I have a function that manipulates the state and **patches** it **partially** by using the standard NGSX `setState` and `patch` functions.

```
function myfunction(ctx: StateContext<MyStateModel>) {

  ctx.setState(
    patch({
      subState1: patch({
        someField1: "some value",
      }),
    })
  );
}
```

**That works.**

**PROBLEM:** Typescript starts complaining about "not assignable" types when I make some of the inner fields **nullable** or **undefined** :

```
export class SubStateModel1 {
  someField1: string | null;
}

OR 

export class SubStateModel1 {
  someField1?: string;
}
```

Then typescript complains :

```
  // TYPESCRIPT NOT HAPPY!
  ctx.setState(
    patch({
      subState1: patch({
        someField1: null,   
      }),
    })
  );
```

The error is :

```
Argument of type 'PatchOperator<{ subState1: PatchOperator<{ someField1: null; }>; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MyStateModel | StateOperator<MyStateModel >'.
  Type 'PatchOperator<{ subState1: PatchOperator<{ someField1: null; }>; }>' is not assignable to type 'StateOperator<MyStateModel>'.
    Types of parameters 'existing' and 'existing' are incompatible.
      Type 'Readonly<MyStateModel >' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<PatchValues<{ subState1: PatchOperator<{ someField1: null; }>; }>>'.
        Types of property 'subState1' are incompatible.
          Type 'SubStateModel1' is not assignable to type 'PatchValues<{ someField1: null; }>'.ts(2345)
```

As we can see, NGSX wraps types in its `PatchOperator` objects but that shouldn't cause any issues.

In particular, the following line of the error should help me but instead confuses me :

```
Types of parameters 'existing' and 'existing' are incompatible.
```

I' suspecting that maybe it has something to do with some nullable field two-levels down in the hierarchy of objects (a patch inside a patch gets confused when there's a null?). But I can't quite put my finger on it.

**TROUBLESHOOTING**

I tried flattening the code :

```
  const obj1  = {
    someField: null,
  };

  const obj2 = {
    subState1: patch(obj1),
  };

  const obj3 = patch(obj2);
  
  ctx.setState(
    obj3 // THE ERROR IS HERE (same error)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that NGXS specifically mentions that those function (`setState`, `patch`) **can sometimes fail to infer the types** in the case of **nested** updates.

see this page, paragraph "Typing Operators" : https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/operators#typing-operators

> You can face cases when the patch operator cannot infer the nested
> type structure. (...) If we don't specify the type explicitly for
> patch, all objects are inferred as unknown, meaning that TypeScript
> cannot tell us that we're doing something wrong or using the wrong
> type.

For example, this StackOverflow question illustrates a similar issue, but with an array : [Update NGXS state for an object inside array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63213492/update-ngxs-state-for-an-object-inside-array)

So I resolved the issue by explicitly specifying the nested types :

```
 // TYPESCRIPT NOT HAPPY!
  ctx.setState(
    patch<MyStateModel >({
      subState1: patch<SubStateModel1>({
        someField1: null,   
      }),
    })
  );
```

I haven't tested yet if it causes issues at runtime, but at least the compiling errors are gone.